# How can i open a pop up box with event information when event url is clicked in the Full calendar?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I used jquery full calendar and this pageload() on document.ready with list of events in calendar. 
Here is my Controller:

```
<apex:page controller="NetworkCalendar" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" action="{!pageload}">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.calendar').fullCalendar({
        header:
        {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right:  'month,agendaWeek'
        },
        editable:false,
        events:[
        <apex:repeat value="{!events}" var="e">
        {
            title: "{!e.title}",
            start: '{!e.startString}',
            end: '{!e.endString}',
            url: '{!e.url}',
            allDay: {!e.allDay},
            className: '{!e.className}'
        },
        </apex:repeat> 
        ]
        });
    $("#dialogbox").dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    modal:true,
    title: "Use of Open event",
    width:300,
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        alert('hello');
    }
    });
    $('#mybutt').click(function() {
        $('#dialogbox').html('<h2>Watch this</h2>An alert box should have opened');
        $('#dialogbox').dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
<apex:composition template="PageTemplate">
    <apex:define name="header">
        <c:LevittHeader ></c:LevittHeader>
    </apex:define>
    <apex:define name="body">
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="containerfull" layout="block"> 
            <apex:form >
                <section Class="bannerWrap">
                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="container" layout="block">
                        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="headingWrap clearfix" layout="block">
                             <h1>Network Calendar</h1>
                             <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn-primary openPoP" value="Create Event" action="{!createEvent}"/>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="searchWrap" layout="block">
                            <apex:inputText value="{!inputstring}" styleClass="searchText" html-placeholder="Search for an Event" />
                            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="searchBtn" onclick="callSearch()" layout="block">
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:actionFunction name="callSearch" action="{!callSearch}" reRender=""/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </section>
                <section Class="calDayList clearfix">

                    <apex:outputPanel id="calendar" styleClass="calendar" layout="block">
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:outputPanel id="dialogbox"></apex:outputPanel>
                    <input id="mybutt" type="button" value="Click Me"/>
                </section>
            </apex:form>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:define>
    </apex:composition>  
  </apex:page>

public PageReference pageload()
{
    events = new list<calEvent>();
     //Get my Events if we have selected the correct option
    if(MyEvents)
    {
        for(Event evnt: [select Id, Subject, isAllDayEvent,StartDateTime, EndDateTime, city__c from Event limit 10000])
        {
            DateTime startDT = evnt.StartDateTime;
            DateTime endDT = evnt.EndDateTime;

            calEvent myEvent = new calEvent();
            myEvent.title = evnt.Subject;
            myEvent.city = evnt.city__c;
            myEvent.allDay = evnt.isAllDayEvent;
            myEvent.startString = startDT.format(dtFormat);
            myEvent.endString = endDT.format(dtFormat);
            myEvent.url = '/apex/DisplayEvent?' + evnt.Id;
            myEvent.className = 'event-personal';
            events.add(myEvent);
            system.debug('EVENT ID'+evnt.Id);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What part of it isn't working?  What have you tried to make it work?  It's really unclear what part of this you're having trouble with.

Comment: i want to open a pop up using jquery when i click the event url in calendar.

Comment: @NickCook..i updated the complete code..my event url in calendar is not working..means the dialog box is not opening

Answer (score 0):

Do you HAVE to use a `#dialogbox`?

Have you tried the default javascript window.Alert()?

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert).

[Some](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp).

[Examples](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp).

Comment: my requirement is dialog box on event url onclick event...